# How to divide parent width equally between its children in css

Tags: css

I want to some divs inside a parent div and i want them to be floated. i want that all the parent space be allocated to its children and to empty gap at end be created.

the number of child are determined by the parent width so i can not use percent.

example:

i want to set children divs width to 300 and the parent width is 1000 so
1000 / 300 = 3 divs will fit but i want that extra 100 pixel be divided equally between children.  now if i set parent width too 1200 four children should fit in the parent.

i need some thing like this

width:calc(100% / (100% / 300));  --> children width

but actually it works if first division be floating point division and second
be integer division. but there is no integer division or mod operator in css calc
method.

any opinion...

Comment: if the number of children is variable, I'd argue that javascript is the best tool for this job

Comment: i don't want use javascript. just pure css.

Comment: You need JavaScript or will have to calculate on the backend.

Comment: @AhmadRahimi how many child you need inside parent div

Comment: Use VW units instead of % http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units , but better to use javascript as suggested above.

Comment: @KamilMaraz what difference would `vw` offer over `%` in this situation?

Comment: I can think of 2 ways : flexbox and this : http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I have bad experience using `%` crossbrowser, because sometimes `calc` will compute 100% from child, but correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: *want that extra 100 pixel be divided equally between children* you mean that equal parts inside the width or just as space between them ?

Comment: whats the reason for wanting to use potentially unsupported (across browsers) CSS rather then fully supported javascript?

Comment: Nice work. Assuming ie8 support isnt needed that that should be the answer

Comment: @hungerstar - - Just for proof of concept - I have added [a pure CSS answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27801535/703717) for this

Comment: @Danield right you are, you can do it with a bunch of css classes. Looks like yours is an expansion upon what `sodawillow` has.

Comment: @hungerstar My solution is isn't similar at all. It uses css tables with a fixed table layout to size the items equally and it uses media queries to show/hide the additional items when necessary. The LESS code also makes it super easy to customize. All you have to do is modify the variables in the LESS mixin

Comment: @Danield eh, it's similar. Multiple CSS classes vs multiple media queries.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to use CSS, you could handle multiple different cases with this kind of code (original idea : http://andr3.net/blog/post/142) - where div represents your childs here :

```
/* one item */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 50%;
}

/* three items */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 33.3333%;
}
```

Or use flexbox : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a PURE CSS solution:

We can use a series of media queries to achieve this. With the media queries in place we can target all of the items after the current iteration to `display:none`.

Now this may sound like a cumbersome task, but if you are using a preprocessor such as LESS - this isn't such a difficult or error-prone task.

All we need to do is set up a few variables in the LESS mixin according to our needs.

Take a look....

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/vEyoZw?editors=110)** (Resize to see this in action)

Usage is simple - just call the LESS mixin like so:

```
.box-layout(myList,li,100px,120px,1,9);
```

Where the mixin takes 6 parameters:

1) The list selector

2) The item selector

3) item minimun width

4) item-height

5) min cols

6) max-cols

Here's CSS (LESS) code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box-layout(@list-selector,@item-selector, @item-min-width, @item-height, @min-cols, @max-cols)
{
  @layout-width: ((@min-cols + 1) * @item-min-width );
  @next-layout-width: ((@min-cols + 2) * @item-min-width);
  @layout-max-width: (@max-cols * @item-min-width);
  @layout-min-width: (@min-cols * @item-min-width);

  @minColsPlusOne: @min-cols + 1;

  @list: ~" `'\n'`.@{list-selector}";
  @item: ~" `'\n'`@{item-selector}";

  @{list} {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 90vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    border: 5px solid aqua;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:0;
    color: white;
  }

  @{item} {
    height: @item-height;
    display: table-cell;
    background: green;
    &:nth-child(even) {
      background:tomato;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: @layout-width) {
    @{list} {
      width: @layout-min-width;
    }
    @{item} {
      &:nth-child(n + @{minColsPlusOne}) {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: @layout-max-width) {
    @{list} {
      width: @layout-max-width;
    }
  }
  .loopingClass (@layout-width, @next-layout-width, @min-cols);
}

.loopingClass (@layout-width, @next-layout-width, @iteration) when (@layout-width <= @layout-max-width) {
  @next: @iteration + 1;
  @media (min-width:@layout-width) and (max-width: @next-layout-width) {
         @{list} {
           @{item} {
            &:nth-child(n + @{next}) {
              display: none;
            }
          }
        }
      }

  .loopingClass(@next-layout-width, @next-layout-width + @item-min-width, @iteration + 1);
}

.box-layout(myList,li,100px,120px,3,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution to my need though it's not a complete general one

thanks for Danield answer. it was near to what i need

here is my the solution in less : ([CODEPEN: see in action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwdWvX))

```
.child {
    float:right;
    height:80px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.looping (@item-width, @index) when (@index >= 1) {

    @media screen and (max-width: (@index * @item-width - 1px)) {
        .child {
            width: ~"calc((100% / (@{index} - 1)) - 10px)";
        }
    }

    .looping(@item-width, @index - 1);
}

.looping(250px, 10);
```